# PCL on ros kinetic

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install ros kinetic on raspberry pi3 with this tutorial [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) and also i clone navigation stack with: `git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git`.
but when i run `catkin_make`, i receive this error:

> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'costmap_2d'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/costmap_2d)
> -- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
> CMake Warning at
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by
> "pcl_conversions"   with any of the
> following names:
>
> ```
> pcl_conversionsConfig.cmake
> pcl_conversions-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "pcl_conversions" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
> or   set "pcl_conversions_DIR" to a
> directory containing one of the above
> files.   If "pcl_conversions" provides
> a separate development package or SDK,
> be   sure it has been installed. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):
> navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeLists.txt:4
> (find_package)
>
> -- Could not find the required component 'pcl_conversions'. The
> following CMake error indicates that
> you either need to install the package
> with the same name or change your
> environment so that it can be found.
> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by
> "pcl_conversions"   with any of the
> following names:
>
> ```
> pcl_conversionsConfig.cmake
> pcl_conversions-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "pcl_conversions" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
> or   set "pcl_conversions_DIR" to a
> directory containing one of the above
> files.   If "pcl_conversions" provides
> a separate development package or SDK,
> be   sure it has been installed. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):
> navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeLists.txt:4
> (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
> "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
> "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> Invoking "cmake" failed

what can i do please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238674/pcl-on-ros-kinetic/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you do a `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions`?

---

Edit: I'm not sure if there are ARM packages available for this package. Otherwise, you have to install from source.
However, I remember that installing PCL on a RPi has been a hassle... See e.g. [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/229788/how-to-building-pcl-laser_scan_matcher-on-raspberry-pi-2/) for an RPi2.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-07-04**:
i follow this question but when i run cmake, i receive error